# How do I specify an option group when upgrading RDS database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a Postgres database in AWS RDS currently running version 9.6.11, and I'm trying to perform a major upgrade to version 10.7. I've followed the [Upgrade Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.html) to create a new version-compatible parameter group, and also created a new version-compatible option group just in case.

When I attempt to initiate the upgrade in the AWS Console, I get this error message.

[image: Current Option Group (integration-postgres96) is non-default. You need to explicitly specify a new Option Group in this case (default or custom) (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination;]

However, there is no apparent place in the RDS console that allows me to specify a new Option Group. What am I missing? Is there something else that needs to be done so that I can upgrade through the Console, or am I required to use the CLI or REST API to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Databases can only be upgraded in the RDS Console if they use a default option group. *(Presumably all databases created in the RDS Console also use the default option group.)*

In my case, the database was created with a tool that invokes the RDS API. In order to upgrade my database, I needed to use either the RDS API or the AWS CLI as described on the [Manual Upgrade](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.Upgrading.html#USER_UpgradeDBInstance.Upgrading.Manual) page. The upgrade command looked like this:

```
$ aws rds modify-db-instance \
  --db-instance-identifier my-database-instance \
  --engine-version 10.7 \
  --db-parameter-group-name my-postgres10 \
  --option-group-name my-postgres10 \
  --allow-major-version-upgrade \
  --apply-immediately
```